# Visual Studio run bar under the tool isn't showing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webforms

The bar under tool isn't showing:

[image: Ref: image 2]

This bar isn't showing . how can I show this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu View -> Toolbars -> Standard

That should work,

[]s